# Quick Search Box doesn't get keyboard focus in Google Desktop

Tags: google-desktop-search

I use Google Desktop as an application launcher. Sometimes Quick Search Box doesn't get keyboard focus.

Repro:

1. Start cmd.exe
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, Quick Search Box will appear.
3. Type blah

Observe: blah appears in cmd.exe

Expected: blah should appear in Quick Search Box.

I have Google Desktop 5.8.0809.23506-en-pb and Windows XP. Is there any workaround? Is it fixed in version 5.9?

Comment: I get the expected results. Slightly dumb question: How do I find out what version of Google Desktop I have?

Comment: Right-click on Google Desktop icon in tray, select About...

Comment: I totally forgot about that icon; I always just use ctrl-ctrl. In any case, this is the version, although I doubt it's still relevant: "Google Desktop 5.8.0811.04345-en-pb"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>It is fixed in version 5.9</strike>

Update: No, it still happens after some time. Restarting Google Desktop fixes the problem.

Comment: @Cawas I did that.

Answer (score 0):

Does it get focus if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> a second time (four times in total?). I used to have a similar problem with Launchy, and it fixed it by hitting the key combination for it.

Comment: If I do this the Quick Search Box disappears.

Comment: What about pressing the combo another time?

Comment: Focus is still at cmd.exe